# catch and care specific exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm running Python 3.7 on Windows 10. I try to execute:

```py
def A():
    try:
        # do something

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: %s." % e)

def B():
    try:
        # do something else

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: %s." % e)
```

I want to "catch" some specific errors like `404 Client Error` and others and send them to function that handles the situation and then return to the previous state in the code. How can I do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: There has to be an exception thrown for you to be able to catch it. What exceptions are thrown all depends on the functions/libraries you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClientError(Exception):
    pass

def a():
    try:
        raise ClientError("boo!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print("All fine now")
```

See how the flow continues after the `try`-`except` block?

```
>>> a()
boo!
All fine now
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it
define all the exceptions I care about

```py
class ClientException(Exception):
    pass

class Exception404(ClientException):
    pass

class Exception500(ClientException):
    pass

def A():
    try:
        # do something
        raise Exception404()
    except ClientException as e:
        print("Error: %s." % e)

def B():
    try:
        # do something else
        raise Exception500()
    except ClientException as e:
        print("Error: %s." % e)
```

So you group your exceptions with the same parent classes
and catch them with the common ancestor class.